# Jquery - Change value in plugin, without running the plugin all over again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a plug-in with a percentage loader. I found the plug-in [here](https://bitbucket.org/Better2Web/jquery.percentageloader)
What I want to do, is to update the percentage shown in the plug-in, according to the percentage a user have filled in a sign-up form. But instead of changing the value, a whole new percentage loader is created.

**Here's my jquery:**

```
$(function () {

var done = 0;

$('.user_field').blur(function () {
    var count = $('.user_field').not(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).length;

    var addTag = count * 25;

    var process = addTag - 100;

    var result = process * -1;

    var done = result / 100;

var loader = $("#topLoader").percentageLoader();
loader.setProgress(done);

});

});
```

You can see the example in function [here](http://beernominate.me/count.html)

Thanks for any guidances! Hope that I gave you enough info to give me a reply.

Comment: I guess loader should be defined outside blur handler. And in blur handler, just update its value inside handler. Or set it in blur handler (but declared outside) but check than it is not already defined. That's said, hard to see really your logic here regarding blur event. I guess you'd like instead to use change event and check for input getting any value defined, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following

```
$(function () {

var done = 0;
var loader = $("#topLoader").percentageLoader();

   $('.user_field').blur(function () {
       var count = $('.user_field').not(function () {
           return this.value;
       }).length;

    var addTag = count * 25;

    var process = addTag - 100;

    var result = process * -1;

    var done = result / 100;

    loader.setProgress(done);

   });
});
```

Comment: That works for me. How can I approve you answer? Its my first question, so don't know how to do that?